# trim email field in php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

given the following code, i need to trim the email field. What would be the best way to do this with the trim function? Whatever i tried gives me errors

```
function email_send($cr) {

    $circ = node_load($cr[0]);
    $pattern = node_load($circ->field_pattern['und'][0]['nid']);


    if ($pattern->field_email['und'][0]['email']) {
        $msg = email($cr);

        $name = '';
        if ($pattern->field_firstname['und'][0]['value']) $name = $pattern->field_firstname['und'][0]['value'] . " ";
        if ($pattern->field_lastname['und'][0]['value']) $name = $pattern->field_lastname['und'][0]['value'];

        $data = [
            'to' => [['name' => $name,'email'=> $pattern->field_email['und'][0]['email']]],
            'subject' => 'header',
            'message' => $msg,
            'pattern_nid' => $pattern->nid,
            'category' => 'reservereceive'
        ];

        var_dump($data);
        return notif_send_email2($data);
```

for instance if i trim $data just before the return function, i see no result.
the email string is an empty string

```
["to"]=>
  string(0) ""

$trimmed_data = array_map('trim', $data);
print_r($trimmed_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `$pattern->field_email['und'][0]['email']` with the trim function in php to return the sanitized email into a variable as shown below:

```
$trimmed_email = trim($pattern->field_email['und'][0]['email'])
```

You can now use `$trimmed_email` to replace subsequent -->`$pattern->field_email['und'][0]['email']`.

Please see the usage of `array_map()` here --> https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp

I suppose you wouldn't need it to trim the entire data.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not simply put `trim($pattern->field_email['und'][0]['email'])`?

Comment: Add this condition : $email = !empty($pattern->field_email['und'][0]) && !empty($pattern->field_email['und'][0]['email'])  ? trim($pattern->field_email['und'][0]['email']) : '';

Comment: Check the email value first, it's exist or not, if exist then only trim that value, if value will be blank it will not work!

Comment: with my test, there is a value in the email field, with spaces... so this is not the problem

Comment: Then it should be work  :                                                                                      
$email = !empty($pattern->field_email['und'][0]) && !empty($pattern->field_email['und'][0]['email']) ? trim($pattern->field_email['und'][0]['email']) : ''